# SQL Update with complex conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables table1(name, num) and table2(index, name, num)
Table1 name column has long names, and table2 name column has both long and short names.

### table1:

```
   name                num
 abc.xyz.com           1234
```

### table2:

### index         name            num

```
1            abc            1234
1         abc.xyz.com       6789
2            abc            1111
2         abc.xyz.com       2222
```

I need to update table2 column "num" with the following conditions:

1. Get the index from table2 where short name of table1.name = table2.name AND table1.num = table2.num
2. Get the long name entry where index of the long name = index obtained from the condition 1
3. update table2.num with the table1.num

In this example, based on the above example

1. we get the index 1
2. we get the second row in table2
3. update the num of second row in table2 from 6789 to 1234

Please help me in writing the sql query for this complex conditions..

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the short name and the long name? give examples, I can only see name column here. how can we know that it is a short name or a long name?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the logic correctly, this query should return the `num` that you want:

```
select t2.*, t1.num
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1name
     on t2.name = t1name.name;
```

If so, you can turn this into an `update`:

```
update table2 t2 join
       table1 t1name
       on t2.name = t1name.name
    set t2.num = t1.num
    where t2.num <> t1.num;
```